# Split a string array into pieces

Tags: php, arrays, split

Let's say I have an array that store like this:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => width: 650px;border: 1px solid #000; 
   [1] => width: 100%;background: white; 
   [2] => width: 100%;background: black; 
)
```

How should I make the `array[0]` string split into piece by separated the ";"? Then I want to save them in array again, or display them out. How should I do it?

```
Array(
   [0] => width: 650px
   [1] => border: 1px solid #000
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally use the [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) to get rid of that extra array element that would occur from the final semicolon...

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $styles):
    // Split the statement by any semicolons, no empty values in the array
    $styles = preg_split("/;/", $styles, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    // Add the semicolon back onto each part
    foreach ($styles as $j => $style) $styles[$j] .= ";";
    // Store those styles in a new array
    $newarray[$i] = $styles;
endforeach;
```

**Edit:** Don't add the semicolon to each line:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $i => $styles):
    // Split the statement by any semicolons, no empty values in the array
    $newarray[$i] = preg_split("/;/", $styles, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
endforeach;
```

Which should output:

```
Array(
   [0] => width: 650px;
   [1] => border: 1px solid #000;
)
```

Unlike explode, which should output:

```
Array(
   [0] => width: 650px;
   [1] => border: 1px solid #000;
   [2] => ;
)
```

Comment: ops, sorry, what if i want to completely ignore the ";"?

Comment: If you don't want the semicolon just delete that second foreach statement inside there.

Answer (score 5):

the explode command:

```
explode(';', $array);
```

You'll then have to append the ';' to the end of each string.

Answer (score 2):

An example

```
foreach($array as $item) {
   $mynewarray = explode(";",$item);
   foreach($mynewarray as $newitem) {
        $finalarray[] = $newitem.";";
   }
   //array is ready
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('width: 650px;border: 1px solid #000;','width: 100%;background: white;','width: 100%;background: black;');

$arr = explode(';',implode(';',$arr));
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr)-1; $i++) { $arr[$i] .= ';'; }

print_r($arr);
```

Will print all of the semi-colon separated lines as separate entities in the array... +1 empty entry which you can delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = "";

        foreach($array as $value) {
                flush();
                $a .= explode(";",$value);
        }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that flush there? You don't flush a toilet when there's nothing in it...